# Magento sql query have no index

Tags: mysql, magento, indexing

I'm having a problem with SQL queries.

Currently I have two magento versions on different servers, both are upgraded from 1.9.2.4 to 1.9.3.2.

The problem, when I check queries with `SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST` I see that they are taking a lot of time. After some researches I have tried to run same query on both servers (directly via SQL command).

Results are 1:15 (68 x 263 rows vs 68 x 961902) in speed, also one of colleagues checked `EXPLAIN SQL` function and saw that in the slower query server there are no key (index). Tried to run adding `USE INDEX ()` and using key from faster query server and seems that is the problem because query went with same results and speed.

In conclusion we thing that some of `MYSQL` configuration are not correct.

Maybe someone could suggest which `MYSQL` configuration or server variables can cause this problem?
Because currently I'm out of ideas. I have tried googling but no results could help me.

SQL query.

```
SELECT  `main_table`.`entity_id`, main_table.`name`, main_table.`path`,
        `main_table`.`is_active`, `main_table`.`is_anchor`,
        `url_rewrite`.`request_path`
    FROM  `catalog_category_flat_store_1` AS `main_table`
    LEFT JOIN  `core_url_rewrite` AS `url_rewrite`
       ON  url_rewrite.category_id=main_table.entity_id
      AND  url_rewrite.is_system=1
      AND  url_rewrite.store_id = 1
      AND  url_rewrite.id_path LIKE 'category/%'
    WHERE  (main_table.include_in_menu = '1')
      AND  (main_table.is_active = '1')
      AND  (main_table.path like '1/2/3/%')
      AND  (`level` <= 3)
    ORDER BY  `main_table`.`position` ASC
```

Comment: I have same problem when I've move magento from server with MySQL 5.5 to server with MySQL 5.7.
Here is my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43225701/mysql-5-5-to-5-7-stopped-using-indexes
Did you found any solution for this? 
I'm currently trying to find where to place "use index" in magento :)

Comment: Posted inside your post with my solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly only MySQL downgrade from 5.7 to 5.5 fixed this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the best indexes would be these 'composite' indexes:

```
main_table:  INDEX(include_in_menu, is_active, path)
url_rewrite: INDEX(is_system, store_id, category_id, id_path)
```

Is there some reason for using `LEFT`?

If you still have issues after adding those indexes, please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace

```
core_url_rewrite.id_path LIKE 'category/%'
```

to

```
core_url_rewrite.id_path REGEXP '^category/'
```

Or add one more condition to the query:

```
core_url_rewrite.category_id is not null
```

[Magento + MySQL 5.7 = Slow Queries](http://itstickers.besthw.net/en/magento-mysql-5-7-slow-queries/)